# Someone keeps hacking into my iPhone remotely, viewing my apps, and logging into my apps. How can I prevent this and see who is doing it?

Tags: iphone, password, remote-control

As my question states, someone is basically getting into my apps on my iPhone remotely. They are able to tell me what apps I have downloaded and who I have contacted through apps.
I have changed my password to iTunes and to the apps themselves but the person can still access my information. 
How is this possible? How can I prevent it? How can I find out who is doing it? Any technical input to explain how things work and practical security tips are welcome.

Comment: You don't tell us what kind of device you have, what version of iOS you're using, if you're jailbroken or not, whether you have ssh installed through Cydia or not, what kind of information they are illegally accessing, what apps they are getting into. Impossible to provide any real help without those vital details. It could be they are gleaning this info through other means (like your PC).

Comment: I echo what cksum says. We can't help much without vital information like what cksum mentioned.

Comment: What evidence do you have that you're being hacked?

Comment: It seems to me if they're logging into your apps, you'd be able to see their various accounts' info.

Comment: This smells like trolling. That, or his iPhone is jailbroken (in which case I have no idea of what could be going on). Honestly, I propose a closing.

Answer (score 7):

100% sure fire way would be to [restore the iPhone](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1414) using iTunes. Should remove any security holes that may have unintentionally been opened.

I would add, you can’t reuse any compromised passwords so you’ll need to securely change them before you re-link any cloud services with your iPhone. It’s almost certain you lost control of your accounts and not that your phone itself was “hacked”

Comment: Also with iOS 12 and macOS Mojave, you will be warned about using the same password for multiple things.